# JPA Cascading not updating the child table

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am having two table with foreign key relation. Now I want while saving data into parent table it will automatically update the parent id into child table. But I unable to save it into child table.
Below my code sample

```
@CrossOrigin
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/m/auth/merchant/order", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MerchantOrder setShippingAddress(@RequestBody MerchantOrder merchantOrder) throws HLRestException {
    if(merchantOrder != null) {
        MerchantOrder order = new MerchantOrder();
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setMerchantOrder(order);
        List<Product> products = order.getProducts();
        products.add(product);
        order.setProducts(products);
        order = merchantOrderRepo.save(order);
        return merchantOrder;
    }
    else {
        throw new HLRestException("Order shipping failed");
    }
}


========MerchantOrder Class=====
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
List<Product> products;

========Product Class=======
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
MerchantOrder merchantOrder;
```

Comment: Your association is not mapped correctly. Here's how to map a bidirectional one-to-many: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Answer (score 0):

Correct your one-to-many relantionship:

```
//MerchantOrder Class
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "merchantOrder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
List<Product> products;

//Product Class
@ManyToOne
MerchantOrder merchantOrder;
```